# Getting TypeError when using Jest to test React Components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to wire up Jest testing with React and I've copied and pasted everything from the [Using Jest with React Tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html) into a demo project and I'm getting a TypeError saying that some Object in `node_modules/react/lib/ReactUpdates.js` doesn't have the function `getPooled()`. As far as I can tell this is happening at `var React = require('react/addons')` inside the `CheckboxWithLabel-test.js` file. I feel like this is something really simple that I'm just overlooking but I can't find anything.

Comment: Have you already set up the `"unmockedModulePathPatterns"` entry in package.json?

Comment: i have `"unmockedModulePathPatterns": ["./node_modules/react"]`

Comment: nevermind. I found the answer on [another stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981486/jest-react-example?rq=1)